# Best books and tools for testing wcf services

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

Hello all i am a beginner to wcf services what are the best books and tools for testing web services ?

Thank you 
Sraven Kande

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many test clients for web services on the internet. In my opinion, the best tool for testing WCF services is *WcfTestClient* provided by Microsoft and its located in the following in VS2010:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
```

The other useful test client is *SoapUI* which you can actually save your test cases.

As for the books, I suggest the following:

[Windows Communication Foundation 4 Step by Step](http://www.amazon.ca/Windows-Communication-Foundation-Step/dp/0735645566/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1347296917&sr=1-1)

[Professional WCF 4: Windows Communication Foundation with .NET 4](http://www.amazon.ca/Professional-WCF-Windows-Communication-Foundation/dp/0470563141/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1347296874&sr=1-5)

[Pro WCF 4: Practical Microsoft SOA Implementation](http://www.amazon.ca/Pro-WCF-Practical-Microsoft-Implementation/dp/1430233680/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1347296874&sr=1-2)